# Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' on line 18

Tags: php, regex

I'm getting the error in the title of this question. Help me find what's wrong in my contact form:

```
<?php

//Prefedined Variables
$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "1";

if($_POST) {
    // Collect POST data from form
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $comment = stripslashes($_POST['comment']);

    // Define email variables
    $message = date('d/m/Y')."\n" . $name . " (" . $email . ") sent the following comment:\n" . $comment;
    $headers = 'From: '.$email.'\r\n\'Reply-To: ' . $email . '\r\n\'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    //Validate
    $header_injections = preg_match("(\r|\n)(to:|from:|cc:|bcc:)", $comment); 

    if( ! empty($name) && ! empty($email) && ! empty($comment) && ! $header_injections ) {
        if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

It seems the problem is here, but I don't understand whats wrong!

```
$header_injections = preg_match("(\r|\n)(to:|from:|cc:|bcc:)", $comment);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$header_injections = preg_match("#(\r|\n)(to:|from:|cc:|bcc:)#", $comment);
```

You must provide a valid symbol at the begining and at the end of you regex, in this example is just `#`, but you can use `/` or whatever you want.

Take a look at this article: [RegEx delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$header_injections = preg_match('/(\r|\n)(to:|from:|cc:|bcc:)/', $comment);
```

Also on your IF condition, you should check `$header_injections` this way:

```
if( ! empty($name) && ! empty($email) && ! empty($comment) && FALSE !== $header_injections ) {
```

As the preg_match can return value that can be casted to boolean and skip your validation.